# Program slider to control camera aperture with python

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I'm very new to scripting in blender, and I'm making an addon to simplify the depth of field process in Blender. I would like to put a slider in my ui panel to control the camera's aperture. I think I need to use a .prop function but I'm not sure. Can I have some help with this? Here is the code for my ui panel:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
    
    
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text= "Focus", icon = "CAMERA_DATA")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("object.add_focus")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("object.remove_focus")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(camera, "dof.aperture_fstop", slider=True)
```

The last line is the one I don't know how to do.
Here is what my UI panel looks like so far:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Photographer add-on does this already: https://blendermarket.com/products/photographer, Nice exercise, though! Just pass the object data and the property `layout.prop(context.object.data.dof, "aperture_fstop")` or `layout.prop(context.object.data, "lens")` Also I'd suggest add a poll method to only display the panel only if the selected object's type is `'CAMERA'` Recommend against using using the index operator `[]` -> `return context.object.type == 'CAMERA'`

Answer (score 3):

**A single property**

Think of a property layout akin to python's `getattr` If we want the value of `foo.bar.foo` it's `getattr(foo.bar, "foo")` never `getattr(foo, "bar.foo")`

**Avoid using  `foo.bar["Foo"]`**

IMO get out of the habit of using, in this example

```
camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
```

which will fail (throw a `KeyError`) if there is no object named camera, which could simply mean its been renamed, or is camera in a different language etc.  It could be the camera linked to another scene, or no scene at all... in which case sliding it would appear to do nought.

**Use Scene Camera**

Suggest in the case of camera, the active camera is assigned to the scene, `scene.camera`.  As long as this is set can use instead. This is the goto camera  when pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> for camera view.

**Object Data Properties**

With a camera active or pinned, the object of interest in the object data properties tab (camera icon) in the properties panel is its data. In the usual case of it being the context object.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Camera']

>>> C.object.data
bpy.data.cameras['Camera']

>>> C.object.data.dof.aperture_fstop
44.41624069213867

>>> C.scene.camera
bpy.data.objects['Camera']
```

**Putting it all together**

Have added some changes to code below.  Without having the operators mentioned in question have replaced with splash screen proxies. Am assuming that the operators use the context object to set the focus object.

Once again use of the scene camera in those operators would make more sense than relying on the camera named "Camera" being the active camera.

A poll method is added to ensure the scene has an active camera. A poll method on your other custom operators could test for active object.  If there is no active object and hence they don't poll, the buttons will appear disabled.

A simple way to have layout in rows is to use one column layout.

Test code.

```
import bpy

class VIEW3D_PT_dof(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_dof"
    bl_label = "Quick Focus"
    bl_category = "DOF"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
 
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.camera is not None
    
    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(icon='CAMERA_DATA')
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
                
        cam = context.scene.camera
        col = layout.column()     
        #col.label(text= "Focus", icon='CAMERA_DATA')
        col.operator("wm.splash")
        col.operator("wm.splash")
        col.prop(cam.data.dof, "aperture_fstop", slider=True)
        

classes = (
        VIEW3D_PT_dof,
        )          
        
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

you must use properties, please check the current  [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html)

please import all libraries you should need.

the class with the panel type and draw method allow create the UI.
in the draw method you should call the property.

Properties can be created in multiple places depending on the purpose. In this case I wrote it in the registry attached to the WindowsManager

properties that are numeric are displayed as sliders (floats, integers...)

please see that all properties has many parameters, as "update" in order to execute some code when the property's value change.

[image: STRUCTURE]

here code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, IntProperty
from bpy.types import WindowManager



class TEST_PT_test(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "TEST_PT_test"
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_category = "TEST"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        
        wm = context.window_manager
        row = layout.box()     
        
        if  bpy.context.active_object.type == 'CAMERA':
            row.prop(wm, "aperture_fstop")
            
            
        
        
def changeaperturecamera(self, context):
    wm = context.window_manager
    camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
    camera.data.dof.aperture_fstop =  wm.aperture_fstop
    
    
        
def register():
    
    WindowManager.aperture_fstop = IntProperty(
        name="aperture_fstop",
        min = 0,
        update = changeaperturecamera
    )
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_test)


def unregister():

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_test)
    del WindowManager.aperture_fstop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

also you can send the int property witout any property

```
layout.prop(context.object.data.dof, "aperture_fstop")
```

but you must create some filters in order to hidde/show the slider only if a camera is selected

Comment: Why this extra WM property? `layout.prop(context.object.data.dof, "aperture_fstop")`, done. Would recommend a poll method for the panel as well, eg.: `return context.object.type == 'CAMERA'`

Comment: @brockmann you right. but he is blender python's newcomer. give some alternatives works fine. right?

Comment: agree somewhat,  suggest using Scene over WindowManager. In which case self is the scene, self.camera is the camera, and context.object is the target object of interest. Could then be used to replace the operators